# Is there a PHP foreach equivelent in Lua?

Tags: php, foreach, lua, lua-table

I have gotten used to programming in PHP with the foreach statement:

Is there an equivalent to this in Lua?

Thanks!

Relevant sections:

```
function renderobjects()
    o1 = object:new{x = 30, y = 30, roomx = 0, roomy = 0, symbol = "t", name = "Tree"}
    o2 = object:new{x = 47, y = 60, roomx = 0, roomy = 0, symbol = "w", name = "Water"}
    o3 = object:new{x = 42, y = 30, roomx = 1, roomy = 0, symbol = "C", name = "Cactus"}
    table.insert(o1, objects)
    table.insert(o2, objects)
    table.insert(o3, objects)
    table.foreachi(objects, object) do
        if player.roomx = object.roomx and player.roomy = object.roomy then
            rb.putsxy(object.x, object.y, symbol)
        end
    end
end

local object = {
    x = 30,
    y = 30,
    roomx = 0,
    roomy = 0,
    name = "Unknown Object",
    touchingplayer = false,
    symbol = "u"
}

function object:new (o)
    o = o or {}   -- create object if user does not provide one
    setmetatable(o, self)
    self.__index = self
    return o
end
```

Comment: Please check here: http://www.lua.org/pil/7.1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is simply:

```
function renderobjects()
    -- ... some of your code elided
    for _,object in ipairs(objects) do
        if player.roomx == object.roomx and player.roomy == object.roomy then
            rb.putsxy(object.x, object.y, object.symbol)
        end
    end
end
```

Note `==` not `=` in comparisons.

In this case `ipairs` works because you are using `objects` as an array.

You can create custom iterators like `ipairs` to iterate over other structured data types using the [generic `for` statement](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.3.5).

Comment: The program compiles just fine, however, nothing renders on the screen. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Try redering something unconditionally to make sure it's not your logic that is flawed. This is a separate issue from the `foreach` question, so you should start a new question if you remain stymied.

Answer (score 2):

Lua has 2 built-in iterators over tables.

pairs() iterates over all entries in a table, but in no particular order:

```
t={monday=1, tuesday=2, wednesday=3, thursday=4, friday=5, saturday=6, sunday=0, [7]="fooday"}
for key, value in pairs(t) do                       
   print(value, key)
end
```

Output:

```
0   sunday
fooday  7
2   tuesday
3   wednesday
5   friday
4   thursday
6   saturday
1   monday
```

ipairs() iterates over table entries with positive integer keys, and is used to iterate over lists in order.

```
l={'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday', not_a_number='fooday', [0]='today', [-1]='yesterday' }
for key, value in ipairs(l) do                                                                         
  print(key, value)
end
```

Output:

```
1   monday
2   tuesday
3   wednesday
4   thursday
5   friday
6   saturday
7   sunday
```

Note that ipairs() ignores non-numeric and non-positive integer keys.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, I read over the LUA documentation and saw it. However, it's a one dimentional array with objects I'm using, I'll post code above.

Answer (score 0):

So assuming that `objects` is a global (or at least outside the lexical scope of `renderobjects`), you could re-write `renderobjects` like this:

```
-- Master list of objects to be rendered and processed
objects = {}

-- Create some objects to render
objects[#objects+1] = object:new{
    x = 30, y = 30, 
    roomx = 0, roomy = 0, 
    symbol = "t", 
    name = "Tree",
}
objects[#objects+1] = object:new{
    x = 47, y = 60, 
    roomx = 0, roomy = 0, 
    symbol = "w", 
    name = "Water",
}
objects[#objects+1] = object:new{
    x = 42, y = 30, 
    roomx = 1, roomy = 0, 
    symbol = "C", 
    name = "Cactus",
}

-- Render the objects in the global list objects.
-- with some special care for player and using the
-- global rb to draw
function renderobjects()
    for _,obj in ipairs(objects) do
        if player.roomx == obj.roomx 
            and player.roomy == obj.roomy then                        
            rb.putsxy(obj.x, obj.y, obj.symbol)
        end
    end
end
```

This uses a standard idiom to extend the list in a table, using the `#` operator to learn the current length of the list. This idiom is similar in effect to `table.insert()`, but usually faster. Note that your code had the arguments to `table.insert` reversed, and so was appending the (probably empty) global list of objects on to each of `o1`, `o2`, and `o3`.

I've also separated out the initialization of the handful of demo objects from the render call. They don't go there....

I rewrote the loop using the generic `for` construction with an iterator returned from `ipairs`. Instead of writing that as `for _,obj in ipairs(objects) do` it could be written as `for i=1,#objects do local obj = objects[i]`. The latter is slightly faster, as it doesn't involve a function call per loop iteration, but it can be slightly less clear to some readers. Either way, clarity of expression should trump all other concerns until you have profiling data to show that this is a bottleneck.